# Force a specific day of the week on a datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am writing an asp.net web app where i want a user to be able to select the end of a pay period.

Pay periods always end on a saturday.

I'm using a calender control, and have given it an onSelectionChanged event handler that looks like this:

```
    protected void forceSaturdaySelection (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Weekending.SelectedDate = Weekending.SelectedDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Saturday - Weekending.SelectedDate.DayOfWeek);
    }
```

This code works, as i want the web application to select the end of the pay period the user selects, no matter which day of the week they select.

My question is, is there a more readable way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't... but that won't stop you from doing it yourself! Create an extension method.. or simply another method to call:

```
private DateTime getPayPeriodEnding(DateTime selectedDate) {
    return selectedDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Saturday - selectedDate.DayOfWeek);
}
```

Extension method version:

```
public static DateTime NextPayPeriodEndDate(this DateTime selectedDate) {
    return selectedDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Saturday - selectedDate.DayOfWeek);
}
```

Then your code becomes either:

```
WeekEnding.SelectedDate = getPayPeriodEnding(WeekEnding.SelectedDate);
```

Or..

```
WeekEnding.SelectedDate = WeekEnding.SelectedDate.NextPayPeriodEndDate();
```

Comment: This does make it more readable, which is exactly what I asked. That being said, I don't think a one liner function needs to have its contents sent out to a different method when this is only being done in one location.

Comment: I disagree. The readability gains from this are evident. It takes 30 seconds to realise what the code does.. but a well named method call can be read and comprehended in an incredibly small amount of time. Favour readability over code size.

Comment: Isn't that same level of readability offered by the name of the function already? i could change it to say something about the end of the pay period instead of saturday, but i don't see how that helps either.

Comment: Not really no. An event is an "entry-point" to the rest of the code.. its name should describe what has just happened (for example, "PayPeriodDateSelected"). Whereas the method that finds the next pay period end date has a specific purpose within your domain. Its up to you really.. I just thought I would give you another point of view :)

Comment: I guess that makes sense. now when I look at the title of my event handler, I notice the name of the method doesn't really match the parameters very well. I should probably change the name of the method to an event name and delegate its logic to a function that takes parameters that make sense with the title of the method. Thanks for your help.